# json parse fails on IE8

Tags: jquery, json

**json -> the response returned back**

```
{"msg":"<DIV><P>Unfortunately we were unable to process your application.</p><BR>Please upload a CV<BR></DIV>", "status":"error"}
```

**The error**

`SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant`

The line with the error

```
var data = $(this).contents().find('body').html();//I have console logged this and holds the above json as a string.
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);// problem is here.
```

for some reason I think, it may be because the html tags because `.text()` works as oppose to `.html()`, however I need to use the `.html()` because it's formatted there with html tags.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: How would this work? Get the html of the ENTIRE document (aka 'body') and pretend it's json?

Comment: var data is an `$('iframe').contents.find('body').html();` which has the `json` above as a string, on ie8 only this does not work, if I simply copy and paste the above json that is returned, and do `data = jQuery.parseJSON('"<div>...blabla</div>"')` this method works.

Comment: That presumes that the iframe has the json inside an html shell. what does the server spit out? A raw json string? or is it really sending out `<html><body>{msg:.....}</body></html>`? If there's no body tag in the iframe, you won't be able to use that jquery find().

Comment: @marcB read the `var data = ...` inline comment, I can get the info but somehow, I think the data so not properly encode or escaped the characters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that a line break in the json? If that's the case, then that's your error. Try eliminating it with something like `data.replace( '\n', ' ' )`.

**Update from the comments**: Val realized that the IE8 parser was in fact borking on his test case, while the original javascript JSON parser handled it just fine. If you need that original parser, it's at: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js as linked to from: http://www.json.org and is pretty much a drop in replacement.

Comment: nope, its not a new line, it's just a copy and paste problem, I tried the replace just incase but, nope...

Comment: Odd. I copy and pasted your exact data there, sans newline, and both `JSON.parse()` and `$.parseJSON()` handle it just fine. Are you sure that's the exact code and data?

Comment: Ah! Mea Culpa, I was on IE9. IE8 eh? That is the first time they introduced a native JSON parser. Maybe its buggy? You could try to use the original javascript parser at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: please update your last comment on your answer, as that github parser fixed the problem :)