# Why does IE[89] convert an array to an object with numeric/string keys?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, extjs4.2

I have the following JavaScript variable that is injected into a web page by the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonData = [{"display_mode":...}];
</script>
```

There is a button on the page that will on demand send this data back via AJAX to have some transformation applied.  This works in Chrome, FF, IE10 and IE11.

In IE8 and IE9, this array is being treated differently, when you use the IE8 debugger watch window, you see

[image: IE8's so called debugger]

When it sends this data to the server it looks like this:

```
'{"0":{"display_mode":"TREE",...
```

Notice how the array is now an object with string keys once it leaves the browser, but it is an object with integer keys in the browser, and a real array when it was sent in the source.

It should look like:

```
'[{"display_mode":"TREE",....
```

What am I doing to trigger this behavior in this browser?  Is there some way to NOT do trigger this behavior?

I'm using extjs4.2.2 to serialize the JSON, just like on IE10, and 11, Chrome and FF.  Only on these versions of IE does it change the array into a keyed object for serialization

Right now I'm working on a solution where I will iterate the fake array and build a new valid array to send back to the webserver based upon the version detected by the extjs framework.  I don't like adding code like this because version detection is fragile.  I prefer this never happen in the first place.

Comment: All keys, whether for Arrays or Objects, are effectively strings in JS. What you seem to have is a serialization issue. So how are you serializing the data? You keep making vague references to data an objects, arrays, real, fake... I can't tell what you have where.

Comment: I don't think any version of IE does that. Is there some more information you haven't mentioned? Incidentally, any property name is converted internally to a string, even an array property.

Comment: `typeof [] == "object"`, i'm guessing the debugger isn't doing much more than a typeof check.

Comment: *"In IE8 and IE9, this array is being treated differently"* In what way exactly, other than the debugger output?

Comment: How are you converting `jsonData` to a JSON?

Comment: @cookiemonster  I'm using extjs to serialize the json (see additional info above)

Comment: @KevinB jsonData is the variable Name.  IE is parsing it as a javascript variable.  I'm beginning to think that is the problem.  extjs4.2 is serializing the variable to json when it sends it to the server.

Comment: I know it's the variable name, i'm not going to include the object in the comment literally... i referenced it by name. I believe the problem is originating from whatever is converting that object to json.

Comment: If extjs is doing it, it's through `Ext.JSON.encode(jsonData)` which appears to properly encode it, so that can't be it

Comment: @KevinB django is serializing the json and its correct for every browser except IE8 and IE9, so I don't think it is the python json serializer.

Comment: what does ext.js have to do with python (i'm new to both, but from what i see extjs is a js library, not python. extjs runs in the browser, and would be what serializes the object to a string to send to python.

Comment: Whatever is doing the serialization is what is causing the problem. IE8/9 both support the built-in `JSON.stringify` method, which works correctly for the given object in both IE8 and IE9 (identically to Chrome/FF etc.) I don't know why a library would define it's own serialization technique for IE8/9 vs chrome/ff when one is built-in

Comment: Well, please see the answer, and keep in mind the only 2 browsers that have this problem are IE8 and IE9.  This is not a problem on the python end, this is a defect within IE and I think the answer pretty much proves that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the original jsonData variable in IE8, it displays like this:

[image: Before re-conversion to to Array]

This will luckily also detect as NOT an array with Ext.isArray().  So, knowing the data structure, I can do the following:

```
var fixed, items, t, i, transaction;

// This fix is here for ie8 and ie9 to turn the arrays back into arrays
if(!Ext.isArray(jsonData)) {
    fixed = [];
    for(t=0; t < jsonData.length; ++t) {
        transaction = jsonData[t];
        items = [];
        for(i=0; i < transaction.items.length; ++i) {
            items.push(transaction.items[i]);
        }
        transaction.items = items;
        fixed.push(transaction);
    }
    jsonData = fixed;
}
```

And after I do that, the debug displays it as:

[image: After the correction is done to the array]

Notice that after my correction, the "object" has something called [Methods].  This makes it serialize correctly as a JSON array.  What I'm suspecting is happening, but I can't completely prove due to IE's crappy toolset is that they do the conversion from array to object while parsing the script tag.  This doesn't cause any operational issues within the browser because these array/objects support length, which allows for loop iteration, Ext.each works, they behave internally like arrays.  But the serializer recognizes the difference and send them back the wrong way.

One other data point as to what is going comes from the javascript console

[image: Javascript console]

jsonData looks like an object, but behaves like an array, in that I can get a valid value back for jsonData.length (this is before I "correct" the array).  And if I create a real object x, and try to get it's length, I get undefined which I would expect.  So I'm going to chalk this one up to yet another IE defect.  If anyone else hits this problem, at least it will be easier to solve.

Comment: The clue that set me on this trail came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007740/json-parse-fails-on-ie8

Comment: When using ExtJS, you can use [Ext.Array.from](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-from) to turn various things into arrays.